# Would somebody help me to draw the following figure in Tikz?

Tags: graph, tikz

Would somebody help me to draw the following figure in Tikz?

[It is a graph we need to include in our latest paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/723FF.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a kind of question you should ask here like this. You are supposed to do your homework by yourself, see help pages (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Anyway, I will give you a start:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[state]    (v_n)                         {$v_n$};
\node[state]    (v_n_1) [below=of v_n]        {$v_{n-1}$};
\node[state]    (v_n_2) [below=of v_n_1]      {$v_{n-2}$};
\node[state]    (v_n_3) [below=of v_n_2]      {$v_{n-3}$};
\node[state]    (v_4)   [below=of v_n_3]      {$v_4$};
\node[state]    (v_3)   [below=of v_4]        {$v_3$};
\node[state]    (v_2)   [below=of v_3]        {$v_2$};
\node[state]    (v_1)   [below=of v_2]        {$v_1$};
\node[state]    (u)     [below=of v_1]        {$u$};

\path[-] (u) edge [bend left] (v_1)
     (u) edge [bend right] (v_2)
     (u) edge [bend left] (v_3)
     (u) edge [bend right] (v_4)
     (u) edge [bend right] (v_n_3)
     (u) edge [bend left] (v_n_2)
     (u) edge [bend right] (v_n_1)
     (u) edge [bend left] (v_n)
     (v_1) edge [bend left] (v_3)
     (v_2) edge [bend right] (v_4)
     (v_n_3) edge [bend right] (v_n_1)
     (v_n_2) edge [bend left] (v_n)
     (v_1) edge (v_2)
     (v_2) edge (v_3)
     (v_3) edge (v_4)
     (v_n_3) edge (v_n_2)
     (v_n_2) edge (v_n_1)
     (v_n_1) edge (v_n);

\path[dashed] (v_4) edge (v_n_3);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me for the mistake. My problem is not the graph actually. I don't know how to mark the distance/comments between the nodes as shown in the figure.